# T4 code wants library project dir, but it gets the dir of the app using the library, instead

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, t4

I am writing a .NET Standard library for use by several apps. In my library project I am using a build time T4 template to gather some build info about the library so that it can be accessible at run time. One of the pieces of info I need is the source (project) directory of the library project. I wanted to do this by getting the CWD and then inferring the library source directory from that. Unfortunately, when I build an app that uses the library, my library's T4 code sees the CWD as the output directory of the app rather than the library. Is there a way for T4 code to get the source code project directory of the library whenever the library is built?

Comment: It's typically up to the executable project to manage the working directory - or really the executor of the executable. So in this case go to the debug properties of the exe project and set the working directory to the project folder. You should be able to use a macro like $(ProjectDir)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more unsuccessful research, I just decided to use a pre-build event that creates a small C# file that defines a static class with a member that is assigned from the CWD.

EDIT:

...but that won't work on both Linux and Windows because shell cmds are different. The proper way is to create a T4 build template that outputs a C# file, something like this:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

using System;

namespace BC.LocationEngine
{
    public static class VersionInfo
    {
        public static string BuildTime = @"<#=DateTime.Now #>";
        public static string BuildPath = @"<#=Host.ResolvePath(".")#>";
        public static string BuildDir = @"<#=Path.GetDirectoryName(this.Host.TemplateFile)#>";
    }
}
```

Notice the 'hostspecific="true".

Then add the C# file to your project.

(BuildPath and BuildDir are two different ways to obtain the same thing)